# Microsoft Lync and Avaya PBX system

Tags: pbx, telephony, lync, avaya

I am a complete beginner concercing Microsoft Lync and PBX systems, so please bear with me.

I have set up a Lync standard server which is running fine. We can chat/audio & video conference on our internal network. Now, what I need is to connect the Lync server to our telephony system, but here is where I get totally lost.

We have an Avaya Integral 5 D pbx box and a netConnect AMP 6 panel.

Are these piece of hardware compatible with what I am trying to achieve? If so, what are the steps to follow from here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the PBX interoperability documentation for Lync available on [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/gg131938)

If it's not supported by Lync natively then you need something that can bridge the gap between Lync and your existing PBX. I'm in the process of investigating [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) as the intermediate.

Hopefully that's enough to get you started. Lync VOIP stuff is FUN!